# Set up react ag-grid column "notBlank" filter by default

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I've set up a ag grid table with a column named astData.astNo. I want this column, by default (on load),  to display only rows where there are no blanks. Manually, I can do it on the UI and it works. But I cant NOT get it to work by default - in other words on load of the table.

```
    const gridOptions = {
        // Add event handlers
        onFirstDataRendered: params => {
            console.log(`onFirstDataRendered event fired`, params);
            var filterInstance = params.columnApi.getFilterInstance("astData.astNo");
            console.log(`filterInstance`, filterInstance);
            filterInstance.setModel({
                type: "notBlank",
                // filter: "s",
            });
            params.pi.onFilterChanged();
        },
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ height: "calc(100% - 25px)" }} className="ag-theme-alpine">
            <AgGridReact
                ref={gridRef} // Ref for accessing Grid's API
                rowData={rowData} // Row Data for Rows
                columnDefs={columnDefs} // Column Defs for Columns
                defaultColDef={defaultColDef} // Default Column Properties
                animateRows={true} // Optional - set to 'true' to have rows animate when sorted
                rowSelection="multiple" // Options - allows click selection of rows
                enableBrowserTooltips={true}
                rowMultiSelectWithClick={true}
                onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
                gridOptions={gridOptions}
            ></AgGridReact>
        </div>
    );
```

The onFirstDataRendered event does trigger but where I'm stuck is, I cannot get the getFilterInstance method where I will be able to set the filter. Can anyone help please?